# How to this error "Undefined variable: selectedType "

Tags: laravel

I have this code below in the registration.blade.php:

```
@foreach($selectedTypes as $k=>$selectedType)
    <li>
        <span class="font-size-sm">{{$k}}</span>
        <span class="font-size-sm">{{$selectedType['quantity']}}</span>
        <span class="font-size-sm">{{ number_format($selectedType['price'], 2)}}€</span>
        <span class="font-size-sm">{{ number_format($selectedType['subtotal'], 2)}}€</span>
    </li>
@endforeach
```

And sometimes it appears an error in the registration.blade.php page "`http://proj.test/congress/1/congress-test/registration`":

```
Undefined variable: selectedType
```

The issue should be when the session "selectedTypes" dont exist or has expired. So maybe is necessary to redirect the user to the page where he select the ticket types if he is in the registration page that has that code "`@foreach($selectedTypes as $k=>$selectedType)...`" and the session "selectedTypes" dont exist. Do you know if this is a correct approach to solve the issue and what is necessary to redirect the user to the congresse details page that has the route:

```
Route::get('/congress/{id}/{slug?}', [
    'uses' => 'FrontController@show',
    'as'   =>'congresses.show'
]);
```

Where the user is in the registration page that has the route below and the session "selectedTypes" dont exist?

```
Route::get('/congress/{id}/{slug?}/registration', [
    'uses' => 'RegistrationController@displayRegistration',
    'as'   =>'congresses.registration'
]);
```

// method storeQuantities() where the selectedTypes is stored in session

```
public function storeQuantities(Request $request, $id, $slug = null){

        $ttypeQuantities = $request->get('ttypes');

        foreach($rtypeQuantities as $rtypeName => $quantity){
                $ttype = TicketType::where('name', $ttypeName)->firstOrFail();
                $price = $ttype->price;
                $selectedTypes[$ttype->name]['quantity'] = $quantity;
                $selectedTypes[$ttype->name]['price'] = $price;
                $selectedTypes[$ttype->name]['subtotal'] = $price * $quantity;

                $selectedTypes[$ttype->name]['id'] = $ttype->id;
        }
        Session::put('selectedTypes', $selectedTypes);
        return redirect(route('congresses.registration',['id' => $id, 'slug' => $slug]));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always check for `$selectedType` variable

```
@foreach($selectedTypes as $k=>$selectedType)
    <li>
        <span class="font-size-sm">{{$k}}</span>
        @isset($selectedType)
           <span class="font-size-sm">{{$selectedType['quantity']}}</span>
           <span class="font-size-sm">{{ number_format($selectedType['price'],
2)}}€</span>
          <span class="font-size-sm">{{ number_format($selectedType['subtotal'], 2)}}€</span>
        @endisset
    </li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks, but like that then there are more content where the selectedTypes is used in that page so there is a lot of white space in the page, so is better to redirect the user to the congress details page if the session dont exist. Do you know how to achieve that?

Comment: You mean to say if `$selectedType` is not set then redirect to a different page?  Redirect from where? The controller or the view? I am confused on what you want

Comment: If the user access this page "http://proj.test/congress/1/congress-test/registration" and the session "selectedTypes" dont exist return the user to the "http://layout.test/congress/1/congress-test".

Comment: For that, you need to check in your controller. Just a simple if condition `if(isset($selectedTypes))         return redirect(route('congresses.registration',['id' => $id, 'slug' => $slug]));` `else return redirect(route('congress.test')`